# Project does not recognize references library

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have a project "TestProject" and a library "TestLib". The project references my library, and it works perfectly.

I installed the NuGet Google Ads package in "TestProject", and it works! However, I would prefer not to include Google Ads in my projects. Instead, I'd like to simply include it in my library. That way, any of my projects using my library will also include Google Ads.

**I deleted the Google Ads package from "Test Project" and I added this in "TestLib", BUT it doesn't work.**

How should I do it?

I received errors about not finding resources, the last error being:

```
The type or namespace name 'Gms' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?) TestProject.Droid
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install a nuget it has part in Portable library and platform specific code, so you will have to have it in both projects unless you have an Android library not Portable.